# Attach to process instead of Dispatch

Tags: com, pywin32

I am using pywin32 and calling the Dispatch function to create a COM object, but this means a new instance of the application is created (in this case PTV Vissim) whenever I call the function. Is it possible, instead, to attach to an already existing Vissim application? This would speed up development, since I wouldn't have to wait for the application to start every time I run a test.

This is my existing relevant code:

```
import win32com.client as com
Vissim = com.Dispatch("Vissim.Vissim.540")
```

Comment: It may be possible using `win32com.client.GetObject` but it depends on the app. It must support it. For example with Excel: http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/attach-to-a-com-instance.html#getobject

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can ***not*** "attach" to an existing Vissim instance as a COM server. Each client connection should be at best backed-up by an independent Vissim instance.

That being said, it is still possible to accomplish your goal, that is - use the command line switch "**-automation**" to launch Vissim.exe, and that running Vissim.exe will act as an automation server as you desired.

--

What is under-the-hood?

The truth is, right in Vissim.exe's startup code, CoRegisterClassObject(CLSID, pUnk, dwClsContext, flags, &dwRegister) is **by default** called with flag = **REGCLS_SINGLEUSE**.

**REGCLS_SINGLEUSE** simply means, ***after*** a client application has been connected to an Vissim class object as hosted by a running Vissim.exe, the Vissim class object's class factory is removed from public view (i.e., not in the OS system's Class Table anymore). This means, a new client connection will have to launch a new Vissim instance in order to obtain the class factory, hence the creation of a new Vissim instance is in order.

However, if you use the command line switch "**-automation**" while launching a Vissim.exe instance, that Vissim.exe will use **REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE** flag to register the class factory instead. That allows multiple client connections to the same running Vissim.exe instance afterwards.

I have more [detailed blog](http://blog.wupingxin.net/2010/01/14/vissm-com-instance-model/) on this matter and other relevant issues [here](http://blog.wupingxin.net/2010/01/14/vissm-com-instance-model/). You might want to check them out at [blog.wupingxin.net](http://blog.wupingxin.net)

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for PTV Vissim, there is an option to start Vissim with the extension -automation (for example: vissim100.exe -automation). If you start PTV Vissim with the extension -automation, it provides PTV Vissim as a COM server in the automation mode for COM scripts that are started subsequently.

See chapter "Starting PTV Vissim via the command prompt" of the PTV Vissim Help.